# Loop through radio buttons and add up totals javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Im new to javascript so please be nice. 
I have a type of a quizz on my website. I need to loop through the checked radio buttons and add up the values when user clicks submit.

After the values has been added up a small pop up window must come up showing the result. If total value of radio button is between 0-10 display msg 1
else if total value of radio button is between 11-20 diplay msg 2
else display msg 3

I have searched the internet but I just cant find a simple working explanation on how to loop through radio buttons and add up totals

My HTML form looks like this

**How Old Are You?**
                     18-21
                     22-30
                     30-42
                     42
                     
                     **What Do you look like?**
                     I look similar to a Thai
                     I am a sterotypical foreigner (white skin, blonde hair, blue eyes)
                     I am a girl
                     I am old
                     
                     **What is your level of qualification**
                     
                     High School
                     College Diploma / Certificate
                     Bachelors Degree
                     Masters Degree or better

```
                  <strong>From which country are you?</strong><br />
                 <input type="radio" value="3" name="country" />Aus, NZ, SA, UK, US<br />
                 <input type="radio" value="0" name="country" />Other country from the once listed above<br />
                 <br />

                  <strong>Is English your naitive language</strong><br />
                 <input type="radio" value="2" name="country" />yes<br />
                 <input type="radio" value="0" name="country" />no<br />
                 <input type="radio" value="1" name="country" />no, but I am fluent<br />
                 <br />

                 <strong>Do you have any experience in teaching English in Thailand?</strong>
                 <br />
                 <input type="radio" value="0" name="experience" />none<br />
                 <input type="radio" value="1" name="experience" />0-1 year<br />
                 <input type="radio" value="3" name="experience" />1-2 years<br />
                 <input type="radio" value="4" name="experience" />2 years +<br />
                 <br />

                   <strong>What is your knowledge of Thai language and Thai culture</strong>
                 <br />
                 <input type="radio" value="1" name="culture" />I know nothing<br />
                 <input type="radio" value="2" name="culture" />I know my basics<br />
                 <input type="radio" value="3" name="culture" />I know slightly more than the basics<br />
                 <input type="radio" value="4" name="culture                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                \   " />My friends say I am Thai<br />
                 <br />

                    <strong>What is your knowledge of Thai language and Thai culture</strong>
                 <br />
                 <input type="radio" value="1" />I know nothing<br />
                 <input type="radio" value="2" />I know my basics<br />
                 <input type="radio" value="3" />I know slightly more than the basics<br />
                 <input type="radio" value="4" />My friends say I am Thai<br />
                 <br />

                    <strong>Do you have any visible tatoos or piercings?</strong>
                 <br />
                 <input type="radio" value="2" />Yes but it is not visible<br />
                 <input type="radio" value="4" />none<br />
                 <input type="radio" value="0" />Visible tatoo or piercing<br />
                 <br />

                 <strong>What gender are you</strong>
                 <br />
                 <input type="radio" value="1" />Male<br />
                 <input type="radio" value="4" />Female<br />
                 <br />
                 <input type="submit" onclick="showTotal" />


                 </form>
```

Comment: The second question seems to be missing some options.

Answer (score 1):

This post here shows you how to get the value of a radio button goup: [How can we access the value of a radio button using the DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604167/how-can-we-access-the-value-of-a-radio-button-using-the-dom)

The simplest answer for you is:

```
function getRadioValue (theRadioGroup)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName(theRadioGroup).length; i++)
    {
        if (document.getElementsByName(theRadioGroup)[i].checked)
        {
                return document.getElementsByName(theRadioGroup)[i].value;
        }
    }
}

var country = parseInt(getRadioValue ('country'));
var experience = parseInt(getRadioValue ('experience'));
```

etc. the you need to add them all up and alert them all up

```
var total = country + experience; // add all the other variables here
alert(total);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

**Just add below scripts in your head section and then you will get total value as below.**

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showTotal()
{
    total = 0;
    $("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function(){
        total += Number($(this).val());
    });
    alert(total);
}
</script>
```