# Get form elements as associative array?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom

I have a problem with html form elements names as assotiative arrays.

```
<form name="ff" action="" method="POST">
<input name="student[john]" value="John">
<input name="student[kofi]">
<input name="student[kwame]">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<a onclick="alert(document.ff.student[john].value);">a<a>
```

I'm getting JS error: "Uncaught exception: ReferenceError: Undefined variable: john"

But this code works fine with form elements names without square brackets.

**UPD:**

I'm puzzled how to get values from radio elements (it represented as a group of radios with same names)

Comment: `document.ff.student[john]` is interpreted such that `document.ff.student` is an object and you are trying to access a property whose name is stored in the variable `john`.

Comment: UPD: I'm puzzled how to get values from `radio` elements (it represented as a group of `radios` with same names)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/604167/218196 has a couple of solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use square bracket notation to access a property with special characters

```
<a onclick="alert(document.ff['student[john]'].value);">a<a>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yBH44/)

Answer (score 2):

Element names are not arrays.

Try:

```
document.ff.elements['student[john]'].value
```