# How to receive values from 'HTML form' to a javascript code?

Tags: javascript, dom

The form includes Radio, Select, Input etc..

```
var variable = document.getElementById('anyId').value;
```

It works fine with input element, but with radio button element it's not working as desired!

On my HTML page (for radio) the code looks something like this,

```
<input type="radio" id="radioValue" name="radio" value="2">Radio_1
<input type="radio" id="radioValue" name="radio" value="1">Radio_2
```

and in the script

```
 var radio_value = document.getElementById('radioValue').value;
```

`radio_value` is always equal to 2, it doesn't matter whether you select radio_1 or radio_2.

Comment: **IDs must be unique!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `getElementsByName`

```
var selectedradio;
var radios = document.getElementsByName("radio");

 for(var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
 if(radios[i].checked == true) {
   alert(radios[i].value);
   selectedradio = radios[i].value;

 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

ID's must be unique. So you should change your code to this:

```
<input type="radio" id="radioValue1" name="radio" value="2">Radio_1
<input type="radio" id="radioValue2" name="radio" value="1">Radio_2
```

And then you can get those values by:

```
var radio_value1 = document.getElementById('radioValue1').value;
var radio_value2 = document.getElementById('radioValue2').value;
//or 
var radio_value=document.querySelector('input[name="radio"]:checked').value; 
// in this last case you don't need even to have id's in the buttons
```

Otherwise trying to read two values with the same ID will give you just the first one of them.

Comment: he could use JQuery and get all the input elements with id = "radioValue" no need to be unique, something like $('div[id^="radioValue"]')

Comment: @drakoumelitos, first: ID's must be unique; second: he didn't tag jQuery.

Comment: @drakoumelitos That is terrible advice. Firstly, ID's need to be unique (please read the W3C specification), secondly there is no need for jQuery to do something so trivial.

Comment: why do ids' have to be unique? it would be better to "group" them using a class but still i dont see any problems if you know what you are doing with ur elements

Comment: @drakoumelitos: Because the HTML standard says so and calls to `getElementById` won't surprise you. The radio button elements are already grouped by `name`.

Comment: @Sergio not grouping ids in a class, grouping elements with the same class in order to be found easier. as he does with the name i guess

Comment: @Felix Kling well ye if you put same ids' you shouldnt expect getElementById to work, but didnt know it was defined in HTML Standards to have unique ids

Comment: Okay, id must be unique, but still how would I know what did the user selected in the Radio?

Comment: @spanecostar: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4196937/218196) to the duplicate question I linked to.

Comment: @spanecostar, you can get the value like : `var radio_value=document.querySelector('input[name="radio"]:checked').value`

Answer (score 0):

Pure javascript for most modern browsers.(works also in ie 9)

if you have just one form and only one group of radio's use querySelector

it's the new proper way.

```
var radio_value=document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked').value
```

You can also easely extend it if you have multiple radio groups and forms.

```
var radio_value=document.querySelector('#YOURFORM input[name="radio"]:checked').value
```