# Meteor radio buttons don't return correct value

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

When I have a form with two radio buttons in Meteor, the first value is always returned in the .val() call. What is the correct way to access which radio button is checked?

---

Here is my sample code:

testRadioButtons.html:

```
<template name="testRadioButtons">
    <form class="main">
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <input name="insuranceDecision" type="radio" value="NoInsurance"/> &nbsp Don't Buy Insurance<br><br>
                <input name="insuranceDecision" type="radio" value="BuyInsurance"/>  &nbsp Buy Insurance<br><br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</template>
```

testRadioButtons.js

```
  Template.testRadioButtons.events({
      'submit form': function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        console.log('running form submit')

        decision = $(e.target).find('[name=insuranceDecision]').val();
        // console.log($(e.target).find('[name=insuranceDecision]'));
        console.log("decision: " + decision); // ZZZZZ Why is NoInsurance always displaying, even when the other radio button is checked.?

    Meteor.Router.to('happyPage');
  }
});
```

And the following are needed to make what I wrote run but do not do anything important.
main.html

```
<head>
  <title>testRadioButtons</title>
</head>

<body>
{{renderPage}}
</body>
```

router.js

```
Meteor.Router.add({
    '/': 'testRadioButtons',
    '/happyPage' : 'happyPage'
})
```

happyPage.html

```
<template name="happyPage">
    <p> Happy page </p>
    <p><a href={{testRadioButtonsPath}}>Test Radio Buttons Again</a></p>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4196937/233382

I have to loop over the individual elements and find the one that is "checked".

Comment: Exactly yeah. An even better jQuery way to do it is $('input:radio[name="insuranceDecision"]:checked').val()

Comment: I need a little more help. Your code exactly works on the client's page. Thanks!  But how do I access this in the submitted form? decision = $(e.target).find('[name=insuranceDecision]').val(); is what needs changing.